# Vue v-model.lazy modifier does not work. Why?

Tags: html, input, vuejs2, onchange, lazy-evaluation

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My first Vue app</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app">
      <input v-model.laze="foo" />
      {{foo}}
    </div>

    <script>
      var a = new Vue({
        el: "#app",
        data: { foo: 1 }
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I would expect to type something, lose focus and then get the output of the `{{foo}}` updated, but instead the `{{foo}}` output gets updated as soon as I type something. I.e. the behavior as if there is no `.lazy` modifier.

I am using the second version of Vue an relying on [the documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#lazy).

Comment: is there a typo ? `laze` or `lazy`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change v-model.laze To v-model.lazy

Try:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My first Vue app</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app">
      <input v-model.lazy="foo" />
      {{foo}}
    </div>

    <script>
      var a = new Vue({
        el: "#app",
        data: { foo: 1 }
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```